# MVC T4 MvcTextTemplateHost and Customized "Controller" T4 Template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, entity-framework, t4, vsx

I am creating my own custom T4 Template that integrates with an ADO.NET Entity Framework Model (.edmx file) included in my MVC Web Application.

### For Reference

Please take a brief look at the following two URLs.

1. Scott Hanselman - "[T4 Code Generation Visual Studio Best Kept Secret](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/T4TextTemplateTransformationToolkitCodeGenerationBestKeptVisualStudioSecret.aspx)"
2. Visual Web Developer Team Blog - Quick Start Guide for ASP.NET MVC Developers

### Short Description of What I am trying to Achieve

Use the T4 engine to generate the MVC Controller class with Action methods based on the ADO.NET Entity Framework Model's Primary Key(s).

### What I Have Right Now

1. MVC T4 Template files **(e.g., Controller.tt, Create.tt, etc...)** have been included as part of my MVC Web Project.
2. I have an ADO.NET Entity Framework **MyModel.edmx file** in the "**Models**" folder.

Based on the Controller name **(e.g. "ProductController")**, I want to retrieve the **[System.Type]** information of the **"Product"** class from the ADO.NET Entity Framework model.
I want to be able to retrieve **System.Type** information the same way as the MVC View T4 files **(e.g. Edit.tt)** as below.

```
MvcTextTemplateHost mvcHost = (MvcTextTemplateHost) (Host);
Type type = mvcHost.ViewDataType;
```

### Final Goal

I want to create the Controller method code-generation to read Primary Key information and etc from the ADO.NET Entity Framework Class via Reflection
**and**
generate basic CRUD operations and method signatures for EDIT, DETAILS, ADD operations etc...

### Where I am Stuck

However, as you can see from **Quick Start Guide for ASP.NET MVC Developers** article, I cannot retrieve **[System.Type]** for **Controller** T4 Template because the **MvcTextTemplateHost** class exposes only **ViewDataType** property for creating MVC Views.

My attempt to retrieve the [System.Type] by the following technique is NOT working because the **modelType** is being returned as **null** meaning it can't find the type.

```
Type modelType = Type.GetType(modelFullyQualifiedName, false, true);
```

I am assuming that this happens because the Entity Framework Model is included as part of my MVC Web Project **and** not included as part of a compiled .DLL library assembly.

### Some Things that Will Help Me Find the Solution

1. Where do I find the Source Code for the **MvcTextTemplateHost** class? If I can find at least the DLL file, I can probably look at how the code loads the Type information entered in the Visual Studio **"Add View" dialog window**.
2. Is there a way to dynamically retrieve System.Type information of a Class included in the Visual Studio project from my T4 Template through the Visual Studio IDE API?

I would really appreciate if anyone can help me on this topic as this will allow me to generate 75% of the code for MVC Controller Action Methods for ADD,EDIT,DETAILS, etc.. and basic CRUD operation code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. You can use Reflector to decompile source code of MvcTextTemplateHost from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Extensions.dll assembly.
2. Yes, you can load type metadata from a Visual Studio using [CodeModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.codemodel.aspx). However, you may be better off reading it from the edmx file directly. Either way, this is a substantial task. There may be a usable example of how to do this in the form of EF T4 template in VS 2010.

Comment: Hi Oleg, thank you for your answer :-)
I read your blogs related to the T4 engine all the time.<br /><br />

I am currently trying by looking at the Source Code of the ** MvcTextTemplateHost** class using the .NET Reflector.<br />
Since I don't have the VS2010 on my computer yet, I guess I will take a look at it later for the EF 2.0 T4 templates.<br /><br />

My 2nd attempt will be to look at the VS Code Model URL you posted.

Thank you so much :-)