# Get controller name in View T4 template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, t4

I have a problem similar to the one described here: [MVC T4 MvcTextTemplateHost and Customized "Controller" T4 Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128003/mvc-t4-mvctexttemplatehost-and-customized-controller-t4-template) but hopefully, simpler.

I have a custom View templates (View.tt, Create.tt) for ASP.NET MVC project. I can't figure out how to get the controller name in these view templates. mvcHost.ControllerName and mvcHost.ControllerRootName both are null in View templates. However, somewhere in the pipeline controller name *is* known, since the view is created int the ControllerName folder. I want to refer to it in the template itself.

Specifically, I want to generate `HTML.ActionLink("Edit", MVC.<controllername>.Edit(id))` instead of `HTML.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {id = item.id})`

Is it possible to get the name of the controller in the View template?

Comment: EDIT: Remove t4mvc tag as irrelevant to the question

Comment: How did you end up doing? I would also like to generate views that are using T4MVC so I need the controller name.

Comment: just put a placeholder /* put controller here */. After all, I am doing it for myself (although several team members "borrowed" it from me :) - so nobody complains!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to get that info in MVC 1.0 or MVC 2. The ControllerRootName and ControllerName properties from the host are for controller T4 templates and not for view T4 templates.

I'll see if we can add more info to the T4 host to enable these properties when generating views.

The reason that the generated file shows up in the right folder is that the MVC project system takes the output of the T4 template and puts it there. The T4 system itself doesn't participate in this process.

Comment: Yes, we would like you to enable these properties!

Comment: Eilon, any idea if this has been added as of MVC 5 (Oct 2014)? I want to add a custom class on `Html.BeginForm`, but as far as I can tell I need to know the controller name in order to specify htmlAttributes.

Answer (score 5):

Since I by convention almost always use the same name for my Controller as I have named the Model, I use this code in my template to get the model name and therefor the controller name:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create new", 
    MVC.<#= mvcHost.ViewDataTypeName.Split('.').Last() #>.Create())
```

Comment: Thanks for idea. I guess, *if* I had one-to-one relationship between my controllers and models that would be a good idea. Given that I've never seen such design anywhere but in the most trivial tutorials - I'll have to wait for more fundamental solution...